# Why [webpack-cli] Error: Unknown option '--display-error-details' [webpack-cli] Run 'webpack --help' to see available commands and options?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, webpack, config

I'm havin the error [webpack-cli] Error: Unknown option '--display-error-details'
[webpack-cli] Run 'webpack --help' to see available commands and options

Even though at the webpack.config flie having -

```js
const path = require('path');
const PATHS = {
    app: path.resolve(__dirname,'app'),
    build: path.resolve(__dirname,'build')
};
module.exports = {
  stats: {
    errorDetails: true,
    children: true
 },
   entry: {
     app: PATHS.app + "/index.js"
   },
   output: {
      path: PATHS.build,
      filename: 'bundle.js',
   },
   resolve: {
      alias: {
        'vue': 'vue/dist/vue.common.js'
      }
   },
};
```

with errorDetail: true

Comment: Can you give more information? it is working for me